# Tell GDB use 8 bytes as a pointer

Tags: c, gdb

I was using GDB on a 64-bit machine:

```
(gdb) show arch
The target architecture is set automatically (currently i386:x86-64)
(gdb) p sizeof(void*)
$1 = 8
```

I had a pointer stored on `0x600fe8`:

```
(gdb) x /xg 0x600fe8
0x600fe8:   0x00007ffff7bd5680
```

I tried to examine what the pointer stored here was pointing to, so I used:

```
(gdb) x *0x600fe8
0xfffffffff7bd5680: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffff7bd5680
(gdb) x /g *0x600fe8
0xfffffffff7bd5680: Cannot access memory at address 0xfffffffff7bd5680
```

It seems that gdb took only 4 bytes as a pointer from `0x600fe8` and sign extended it.

How could I fix this? Thanks.

---

#### Research I've done:

Didn't find my scenario on:

- [GDB doc](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/)
- Google

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but try `x/xg *(void **)0x600fe8`. I'm guessing GDB is reading only 4 bytes because it has no type information for the address 0x600fe8 and is defaulting to `int` per standard practice for archaic-period C (lots of these low-level tools haven't really ever caught up to the modern day).

Comment: Just a guess... try: `x *(void *)(uintptr_t)0x600fe8` ... though `void` should be replaced with the actual type, or the compiler won't know how much data to collect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
x *(void**)0x600fe8
```

As @zwol mentioned in the comment, gdb needs type information about the operand to decide its size. This type casting tells gdb that `0x600fe8` is a pointer to a pointer.